# Word for when someone intentionally ignores someone's valid excuse from a punishment and then enforces that punishment anyway?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, terminology, legalese

Is there a word (or legal term) for when someone (usually an authority figure) intentionally does not acknowledge a person's justification from an adverse action, then enforces that adverse action against the person anyway, as if they never said anything?

My friends have suggested words like "gaslighting", but that doesn't fit what I want to convey. It's something a vindictive politician or professor might do. Very frustrating experience for the victim.

Example:

Johnny must be in Mr. Malvoso's class by 8:00 or he'll be banned. Johnny arrives at 7:30 but can't enter b/c the only door is locked. Mr. Malvoso is on the other side of the door and sees this. Johnny sees Mr. Malvoso and says "Please open the door. It's locked". Mr Malvoso hears, but does not acknowledge Johnny's words. Johnny repeats himself but he continues to stare at Johnny and do nothing.

Then at 8:02, Mr. Malvoso opens the door and tells Johnny, "Academic Policy requires you to be in class by 8:00. Because you failed to do this, you are banned from class". Johnny protests that Mr. Malvoso knew he couldn't enter and refused to act, but Mr. Malvoso pretends not to hear it. Later that day, Mr. Malvoso sends Johnny a notice that reads "You are hereby informed that you are banned from Mr. Malvoso's class for failure to attend by 8:00".

Comment: That's _persecution_!

Comment: Your example is gaslighting since the gaslighter makes the sane person the crazy one. Also: Might is Right. Don't tell me how to treat my enemies. Sentence first, verdict afterwards (Red Queen).

Comment: Also maybe a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)).

Comment: Broadly that's called 'lying'  and might well be 'fraud.' I for one see no connection to gaslighting or Catch 22, and I suggest 'persecution' is much too far-reaching to be useful here.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.